# iOS Constraints issues with bigger screens (iPhone6 and 6Plus)

Tags: ios, constraints, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus, size-classes

I've a problem in my constraints, with display 3.5 inch and 4 inch it always working perfectly but in iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus (4.7 inch and 5.5 inch) I cannot set the right constraints.

This is an example  (I drew in red the problem):
[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having a Leading Space and Trailing Space constraint on the Example view, add a Horizontally Center In Container.

[image]